# How do I make remote desktop connection resolution to have the same resolution as the remote desktop?

Tags: windows, display, resolution, remote

So I have a small screen now and I am connecting to a remote PC that has a 1440p screen.

When using Teamviewer, it lets you preview the remote desktop as if it were 1440p, yes the image gets less sharp, but you get more space.

How do I do the same with the Windows Remote desktop connection application?

Comment: Teamviewer shows you the actual remote display, while RDP renders it based on the resolution of your local display. Unfortunately can't test, but you might have some joy by adjusting the DPI scaling settings rather than the resolution.

Comment: What I always find an odd omission is that the Mac version of Windows RDC just has a nice checkbox with "Fit session to window" which seems like the most obvious way to achieve it, yet afaik it's never been in the Windows version.